# algorithm to find best match that may return none

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have some inputs that may be temporarily unavailable and that have an error associated.

```
struct sensorVal
{
    bool available;
    double error;
    double val;
    bool betterThan(const sensorVal* that) const;
}
```

I'm looking for an algorithm that will find the best *available* input. My best attempt so far is to use `min_element` as follows:

```
bool sensorVal::betterThan(const sensorVal& that) const
{
    if (available)
    {
        if (that.available)
            return (error < that.error);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool betterThan(const sensorVal& lhs, const sensorVal& rhs)
{
    return lhs.betterThan(rhs);
}

std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator 
find_best(const std::vector<sensorVal>& inputs)
{
    std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator best;

    best = min_element(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), betterThan);

    if (best->available)
        return best;

    return inputs.end();
}
```

This works fine except when all inputs are marked unavailable. In this case best is set to `inputs.begin()` and I then need to test whether it is available.

I would prefer to have best set to `inputs.end()` which is already catered for in my code.

Is there an existing algorithm that can find best match that can return that there are no suitable members? Or a way of rephrasing my test so that best is set to `inputs.end()`.

thanks

Comment: This is a case where having higher order functions ([filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29) in particular) would be convenient. I couldn't find, however, something like it in the STL. Something like [remove-if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) could be useful.

Comment: It looks to me like you have working code, and only have to check available one extra time.  Is this really a problem?

Comment: @btilly Yes I have something that works. I wanted to know whether there was an algorithm that did what I wanted already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::accumulate` instead, but I think the solution you already have is better.

```
struct best {
  std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator end;

  explicit best(std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator end) : end(end){}

  std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator operator()(std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator l, std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator r) {
    return (r->available() && (l == end() || r->error < l->error)) ? r : l
  }

};

std::vector<sensorVal>::const_iterator 
find_best(const std::vector<sensorVal>& inputs)
{
  return std::accumulate(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), inputs.end(), best(inputs.end());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it considered good practice to make the functor constructors explicit?

Comment: It's considered good practice to make single argument constuctors explicit nuless you have very good reason not to, but it doesn't really matter in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want to make it look a little better?

```
best = min_element(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), betterThan);
return best->available ? best : inputs.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use std::partition() to sort the vector into available and unavailable inputs. Then use min_element to find the best within the available subset.